# How to Install SpecFlow in VS 2015 Express

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I need to install SpecFlow in my VS 2015 Express version, i just want to know that is it possible to install it in VS 2015 Express version. if yes then how, please suggested me a proper and better way.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK VS Express does not support Extensions and so you can not install the SpecFlow Extension. 
Is there a reason why you are not using the Community Edition (https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/)? This supports loading extensions.